# Needing to change the email address emails are coming from

Tags: civimail, email

I am looking for some help on two issues:

When Mailing contacts who have booked for an event, the email is coming from an email address I don't want to use. How do I remove the preferred email address and add a new one?

Likewise, when manually registering an event participant, the default email address that the booking confirmation would come from is also wrong, and I wish to remove this completely and add a new one/

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your outbound mail configured?  ie when mail leaves Civi, where does it go? Check at Administer > System Settings > Outbound Email

Answer (score 1):

I'd look first at the event settings themselves.

(From the manage events page, choose configure and then click to the online registration tab)

At the foot of the page is the email confirmation settings
[image: email confirmation fields]

This is what governs the "from email address" in any confirmation message.

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Thanks Craig. Unfortunately this has not solved the problem. The email address showing up in that section is different from the 'preferred'/default one that I am trying to get rid of - which only appears in two places: When mailings contacts who have already booked for an event, and secondly, when manually registering an event. I want the option of this email address to disappear as it is incorrect

Comment: Hi Lara,

I'm struggling to think of where you mean (it's been a day) could you take a screenshot of the pages you're looking at, and I'll see if that riings any bells.

Answer (score 1):

The default email for messages is set in Administer >> CiviMail >> From Mail Addresses and setting that to what you want should help (but I'm not quite clear on your examples. In your first case, if its an online booking then Craig's suggestion should work. Perhaps you can be more specific.